Where are these ancient places described in a Sumerian tablet?
Recently, in a museum, I saw a tablet of ancient literature from Mesopotamia, specifically showing part of the ancient Sumerian story Enki and Ninhursag:

The translation to English (provided in the museum and also available in the Electronic Text Corpus of Sumerian Literature) is as follows:

"May the land of Tukriš hand over to you gold from Ḫarali, lapis lazuli and ……. May the land of Meluḫa load precious desirable cornelian, meš wood of Magan and the best abba wood into large ships for you. May the land of Marḫaši yield you precious stones, topazes. May the land of Magan offer you strong, powerful copper, dolerite, u stone and šumin stone. May the Sea-land offer you its own ebony wood, …… of a king. May the 'Tent'-lands offer you fine multicoloured wools. May the land of Elam hand over to you choice wools, its tribute. May the manor of Urim, the royal throne dais, the city ……, load up into large ships for you sesame, august raiment, and fine cloth. May the wide sea yield you its wealth."

Some of these places are identifiable from a quick search: Marhasi and Elam were in modern-day Iran, Magan was in the modern-day Oman and UAE, and Meluha was (probably) in modern-day India. All of these are shown in the following map that I found on Wikipedia:

Tukris is a mystery, and Harali is probably not this? Does Urim refer to Ur or something else? Is it at all possible to identify what regions were referred to by "the Sea-land" and "the Tent-lands" in this passage?

"Enki and Ninsikila/Ninhursaga" is included in The Harps that Once...: Sumerian Poetry in Translation, edited by Thorkild Jacobsen (Yale University Press, 1987). The myth has survived in three versions: a short one from Ur, a longer one from Nippur, and a fragment of a third one. The section cited in translation has only come down to us in the version from Ur and it is not certain where it may be inserted (Jacobsen, p. 188), but Assyriologists seem to have agreed to on where to insert it, since Thorkild Jacobsen and the translators of the text in the Electronic Text Corpus of Sumerian Literature (ETCSL) insert in the same place.

According to Jacobsen, Tukrish "was situated north or northeast of the later Assyria".
Harali is not mentioned in the translation published by Jacobsen. Instead, we get "gold of the river beds".
The scribes of the Assyrian period identified Meluhha and Magan with Ethiopia and Egypt, respectively, but modern scholars "would like to identify at least one of them with India".
Marhashi was probably in the region to the south and west of Lake Urmia in the north-west of present-day Iran.
The location of the Sealands and Tent lands is unclear.

Jacobsen adds, "The order of the names, to stress the far-flung nature of the trade involved, seems to be by diametrically opposed pairs, Tukrish-Meluhha for north and south, Marhashi-Magan for east and west."
There is no uncertainty about the location of Elam since it is well-known for its military campaigns against Babylonia.
The "manor of Urim" is translated as "manor of Ur" in Jacobsen's edition, so that identification is also clear. If Wikipedia is to be believed, Urim is the more literal transliteration of the Sumerian name, whereas Ur is a transliteration of the city-state's name in Arabic and Hebrew.

You don't have to trust Wiki on this, either. Black et al only use Urim instead of Ur, Kramer states in unequivocally, as does the ETCSL: "Ur (an anglicisation of the Sumerian Urim)."
